# How to replace debounceTime(0) to emit when needed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, debouncing

I have a similar use case to this

```
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'
import { map, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators'

const items$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
const size$ = new BehaviorSubject(10);

const visibleItems$ = combineLatest([items$, size$])
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(0),
    map(([items, size]) => items.slice(0, size))
  );
```

And some times I have this scenario

```
const onData = bigArr => {
  items$.next(bigArr);
}
```

Sometimes this

```
const changeSize = () => {
  size$.next(20);
}
```

And sometimes this

```
const onData2 = bigArr => {
  items$.next(bigArr);
  size$.next(10);
}
```

I don't want to trigger the `visibleItems$` observable flow multiple times, so a solution that I've found is use the `debounceTime` operator with 0 ms to perform the `onData2` method without running the pipe operators twice, but it is a bit hard to reason this operator (at least from the first glance). How can I replace it, so my code is easier to understand?

Comment: You got two streams `$items` and `$size`. Your `visibleItems$` will not trigger until your `$time` and `$size` triggers at least once, because its `combineLatest`  wait for all input Observables to emit at least once before it starts emitting results What is the problem ?

Comment: I would say it is a bad practise, just because it is hard to reason what `debounceTime(0)` is doing here, from the first glance. And what it does is similar to what `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)` does. And we know that in most cases that is a bad practise. It is hard for me to propose something elegant here (need to know a bigger picture), but as a better way (easier to understand), you could use another stream const `show$ = new Subject()` and use it together with other streams in `combineLatest`. And then, when you want `visibleItems$` to emit, call `next` on it - `this.show$.next()`

Comment: When `items$` and `size$` emit at the same time the `visibleItems$` will be triggered twice unnecessarily, so  I've used the `debounceTime(0)` operator to ignore the first emit, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to achieve this behavior.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using `debounceTime(0)` to suppress emissions that occur on the same event loop tick. FWIW: I don't feel it's hard to reason about about (*but I've been using rxjs for a little while now, so I'm pretty familiar with the behavior of these operators*) :-)

Comment: @BizzyBob - "hard to reason"  I ment when you read code in real life, to understand what does `debounceTime` here, you need to also find `onData2` function. Otherwise you are left with your imagination to struggle what value this. might serve here (since as we know, this operator wasn't designed for this purpose, as stated in docs). F.ex. if both streams were synchronous, adding `debounceTime` would make outer stream asynchronous. Maybe that was the purpose, some developer might think...? And besides that, if later `onData2` function is removed, `debounceTime` remains just a garbage.